# How did Thor know Loki was on the plane?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-avengers

During the movie Avengers, we are first introduced to Thor when he crashes the party on the plane, taking his brother Loki to get the location of the Tesseract from him.  How did Thor know that Loki was on the plane?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thor seems to have some unstated capability to track and find Loki.  He knew exactly where the S.H.I.E.L.D. jet carrying Loki was when he intercepted it.  Then later in the film, after being dumped out of the Helicarrier, he knows to go to New York City to stop Loki.  If he is capable of always finding Loki, it explains both of these.

Comment: The plot hole in this is not knowing where he was between Thor and the jet. Though, something I hope they answer in Thor 2

Comment: @TylerShads The reason for this might be that *Loki* was on quite a different place, like a galaxy far far away (where the *Chitauri* came from, too). At least he likely wasn't on one of the 9 worlds to which limiting *Thor*'s sight makes sense (it even makes sense to limit it to earth only, given his special interest in that world, and his employment of *Heimdall* to keep it under surveillance).

Answer (score 25):

Heimdall, (guardian of the Bifrost aka rainbow bridge) can see all, thus he tracked down Loki's exact Location and directed Thor to Loki. Odin used dark energy to transport Thor to earth since the rainbow bridge is destroyed.

If you watch the scene closely when Thor and Loki are arguing a top a mountain after Thor takes Loki from the plane. You can clearly see Odin's two Ravens Huginn and Muninn flying by. So Odin is aware and present during their argument... Brilliant move by the film maker.

Also Oak trees are representative of Thor in ancient Norse mythology. Which just happen to be surrounding Iron Man and Thor as they fight.

This movie is full of geek win.

Comment: I've got to give this a vote for the Ravens, I've never spotted that!

Comment: Hah, when watching it recently I noticed those birds and thought, *"hey, would be cool if that were Odin's ravens"*. I can't believe I wasn't the only one thinking that, if true or not.

Answer (score 1):

It is not stated in the movie, however one can assume one of the following:

1. From the events in Thor that Heimdall the all seeing gatekeeper of the rainbow bridge Bifrost was able to "see" Loki and keep tabs on his location. After Loki appeared on Earth Thor needed time to prepare a way to journey to Earth (I assume that the rainbow bridge had been repaired between the events of the two movies)
2. Thor has access to some device that is able to track the Tesseract when it is active. Since it was not active until Loki transported to Earth. Thor was unable to track Loki until the Tesseract  was active.
3. The Tesseract is a crystal ball only when is became active was when Thor could again see what Loki was doing
4. Some being told Thor, Loki was alive and on Earth
5. Thor is technically a god

Comment: Well sad to say but most of this is wrong.  The Bifrost is gone at the end of Thor.  Loki even states "What kind of dark magic did the old man have to conjure up to get you here" Implying that it probably took Odin himself a lot of effort and magic in order to transport Thor to Earth.  I do applaud the effort though for thinking outside the box.

Comment: I would like to know my mis-steps in logic for the other items. Also please consider another option. I assume the Chitauri where the ones that helped Loki open the Tesseract (because otherwise why didn't he open it whenever). Could some other alien race helped Thor get back to earth?

Comment: I can't quite say if any alien race helped Thor or not.  I hope this issue will be mentioned/tackled in Thor 2 but my judgement rests soley by the comment Loki made when he firs talked to Thor in the movie on the mountain that Odin summoned some kind of power to send him there.  How they got back is also a blatant mystery.  Unless there is something in the comics that I do not know.

Comment: As far s the tesseract, it seemed to require a lot of human engineering (that Loki had no knowledge or desire to know of) to make it open the portal (hence him turning Selvig)

Comment: As for the alien races I agree with you. There is not enough information to go on. Tesseract wise I partially agree with you. Maybe there is a reason that Loki is not touching the Tesseract. The reason I say that is to the best of my knowledge Loki never once actually touched the Tesseract.

Comment: You are quite right, I do not recall him ever actually touching it, but just carrying it in the suitcase.  Considering the device it was placed in at the end of the film when Thor was leaving with him, it is dangerous even to Asgardians.

Comment: I offer another support to the theory that handling the Tesseract is dangerous. In Captain America movie the Red Skull is vaporized by touching the Tesseract and it eats through the plane. On another matter I offer another theory based on the Thor movie. Loki at one point tells Heimdall I think that they are ways in and out of the city that he can't even imagine. In theory these could have been discovered in the time between the two movies.

Comment: @TylerShads As to how they returned to Asgard at the end is probably somehow by means of the tesseract, since we see them both hold the canister (Thor even nodding to Loki in order to put his hands on it, I think) with the tesseract in it (maybe it wasn't just a canister but some device powered by the tesseract) and we see this cyan "tesseract-light" when they "beam up".

Comment: @ChristianRau Good point, like I've said before, most of this *should* be cleaned up in Thor 2..I would hope RE: Orion

Comment: @OrionDarkwood The Red skull [was not vaporized](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/6317/1027) by the Tesseract.

Comment: @Keen, I only have a passing knowledge of the comic book series. I based my comment on the events of the movie.

Comment: @OrionDarkwood I have no knowledge of the comic book series.  My comment and linked answer were purely based on the movies.